# How to get a WebRole deployed on IIS instead of IISExpress?

Tags: azure

There is an Azure WebRole and the approproate Service in a solution. Solution is unser source control. The problem is that my team-mate gets the sources to his workstation, opens them in Visual Studio, runs the service and gets the WebRole deployed on local IIS, while I can only see it on IISExpress in the same workflow.

We compared the settings of projects in Visual Studio and could not find differences.
We compared the source files after running them from Visual Studio and did not find differences,

Can anybody tell us is there a way to explicitly set the target IIS engine for deploying a Web Role in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the properties for the Azure project

[image: Azure Settings Screenshot]

You should be able to set it to use IIS instead of express.

Comment: Thank you for relpy.
Nevetheless, I have already found these settings in properties.
Even though I am not sure they will fully resolve my problem, you've given a relevant answer.

Additionally, I cannot see the screen capture. Please make sure it is inserted properly in your answer, and I will accept it then.

Comment: Let me know if you still can't see it.  Also, did you look at your suo files to see if there was a difference there, usually those are not in source control.